# How to get value from one form to an other?

Tags: c#

I made a form for deleting/removing products.

Now my question is how do I get the value from one form to the other so I can use this to update the amount of products or delete the products from a database?

I'm trying to get the value of tbAantal.Text, so I can use this in my other form to update the amount of products.

Or should I do it in a other way?

```
public partial class Bevestiging : Form
{

    public Bevestiging()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Aantal = 0;

    }



    public int Aantal { get; set; }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int aantal;
        if (!int.TryParse(tbAantal.Text, out aantal))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("U kunt alleen numerieke waardes invullen.", "Fout");
            return;
        }


    }


    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        Close();
    }

    private void BtUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Aantal++;
        tbAantal.Text = Aantal.ToString();
    }

    private void BtDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Aantal--;
        tbAantal.Text = Aantal.ToString();
    }
```

So I can use this to update it here:

```
private void gridGeregistreerd_ColumnButtonClick(object sender, ColumnActionEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new Bevestiging();

        if (DialogResult.OK != dialog.ShowDialog()) ;


    }
```

Comment: It looks like you've already done it.  Can't you access dialog.Aantal?

Comment: Just create a getter for `tbAantal.Text` in your `Bevestiging` form class.
`public string AantalText { get { return tbAantal.Text; }`
Then you will be able to use it inside `gridGeregistreerd_ColumnButtonClick` like `dialog.AantalText`.

But you already can use `Aantal` in the same way and it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already made the public property "Aantal" on your first form with the right get/set so to retrieve the value on your second form use this:

```
using (Bevestiging myForm = new Bevestiging())
{
    DialogResult result = myForm.ShowDialog();

    if (result != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        int returnedValue = myForm.Aantal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you form, you have already define a public property :

```
public partial class Bevestiging : Form
{
    public int Aantal {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Then in your callee form, you can access it :

```
private void gridGeregistreerd_ColumnButtonClick(object sender, ColumnActionEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new Bevestiging();

    if (DialogResult.OK != dialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        int aantal = dialog.Aantal;
        /* Save it to database or whatever you want */
    }


}
```